# I have given correct parameters and headers for POST method, but response code is 400

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-400, bad-request

I was trying to integrate SnapChat login kit to my web application. I was able to get the authorization code from the SnapChat, but I am having trouble getting the access token.
I have done FB, Google, Instagram login integration perfectly fine, but this one I am totally lost.

I have tried to encode the parameters, change the order of headers, but all the time it gives me 400 bad request.

```
try {
        URL url = null;
        if(service.equals(APIConstants.GOOGLE))
            url = new URL(SNSIdentifications.GOOGLE_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL);
        else if (service.equals(APIConstants.FACEBOOK))
            url = new URL(SNSIdentifications.FACEBOOK_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL);
        else if (service.equals(APIConstants.INSTAGRAM))
            url = new URL(SNSIdentifications.INSTAGRAM_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL);
        else 
            url = new URL(SNSIdentifications.SNAPCHAT_TOKEN_REQUEST_URL);
        conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        if(service.equals(APIConstants.SNAPCHAT)) {
//              String userCredentials = URLEncoder.encode(client_id + ":" + secret, "UTF-8");
            String userCredentials = client_id + ":" + secret;
            byte[] data = Base64.getEncoder().encode(userCredentials.getBytes());
            String authorizationHeaderBase64 = new String(data);
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationHeaderBase64);
//              conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
                //Integer.toString(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length)
//                  conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString(payload.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length)  );

            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
//              writer.write(URLEncoder.encode(payload, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(params);
            writer.flush();
            System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode() + " " + conn.getResponseMessage() + " ");

        } else {
            writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(params);
                writer.flush();
        }
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            return new JSONObject(fetchResponse(conn));
        } 
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I should expect access token, refresh token, and expires_in values from the code above, but unfortunately it cannot, because of 400 bad request error.

Comment: Are you getting the same error when you post from Portman or Insomnia?

Comment: Without seeing the signature of the server side REST interface its hard to tell what you are missing. Http 400 means that some parameters may be different than expected. But like i said its hard to tell without the other side of the coin.

Comment: @ArpanKanthal I am not sure about Portman or Insomnia, but I use Postman to check the data. It shows the same result.

Comment: @arnonuem I am not really sure what you mean by signature of the server side. But referring from snapchat (https://docs.snapchat.com/docs/login-kit : 2.5 Exchange authorization code for refresh and access token), the parameters needed and the headers needed are all filled up in my code.

Comment: I just glanced over the api docs, are you using the https://accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/oauth2/token? If yes, the api expects a Base16 encoded version of the clientId:clientsecret and not Base64 like you have done in the code above. Can you try Base16 on Postman and check?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using accounts.snapchat.com/accounts/oauth2/token as URL. Okay I will try base 16. I saw example code and it was using 64, so I think I just used 64.

Comment: @ArpanKanthal Base16 still doesn't work... 400 Bad request again

Comment: I used error stream to see what is wrong, and found out that "code" was issued to another client, even if I use fresh code every time.

Comment: @ArpanKanthal I managed to figure out the problem(s)! Thanks for helping me out. You really did help me to think through the process and check all of the small details!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It turned out it was several combinations of problems.
When you are having an issue as I posted, please do check the followings:

1. Make sure you are using correct Client Id and Secret.
2. If you are adding Code Challenge and code challenge method parameters, you need to have code verifier to get access token. If you don't have these parameters, you don't need to worry about getting an access token.
3. When setting a header "Authorization" use base64 encode, not base16. (Snapchat page says base16, but in an example, it's in 64).
4. Check your urls, id, secret once again with those to get the authorization code.

:)